# Concurrency Issue on Hashmap Stored in Apache Ignite

Tags: caching, concurrency, hashmap, ignite

I am developing a Clustered Web Application with different WARS deployed, so I need session sharing (and not only this). I've started using Ignite as a good platform for Clustered(Replicated) cache server.
The issue I reached is this:
My cache Key is String and Value is a HashMap

```
CacheConfiguration<Integer, Map<String,String>> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<>("my_cache");
```

I am using this cache as a WEBSESSION. The issue is where one servlet gets the Map, Put some session specific values, and put it back to Ignite. After the first servlet gets the cache, second one enters and because it finishes after the first one, the second put will kill first one changes.

So my exact question is, what's the pattern to have concurrent map access issue solved is a high efficient way (without whole object locking).

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a bit weird to me, because this scenario should be only possible when two there are two concurrent requests working with the same session. How is this possible?

But in any case, you can use `TRANSACTIONAL` cache for web session data. This will guarantee that these two requests will be processed within a lock and the data will be updated atomically.

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
    <property name="name" value="web-sessions-cache"/>
    <property name="atomicityMode" value="TRANSACTIONAL"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you Valentin for your answer but its not correct.
Think the following scenario:
Servlet_DoGet_Method() {
    Map<String, String> session = cache.get("token"); 
    session.get("some_session_key");
    long_running_task_onDB();
    open_close_files();
    session.put("some_session_key", 1000);
    cache.put("token", session);
}

Now during this servlet get method running, if somebody get the Token session map, its still the OLD map and not the map with value 1000, the first method finishes and after that the second so we loose the first method some_session_key changes on map

Comment: As you said, If I use TRANSACTIONAL cache mode, what happens at the end, while the second one is going to commit the transaction? Exception ? Overwrite(Like no transaction)?

Comment: Are you using Ignite's web session clustering (https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/web-session-clustering)? If so, then the request will be processed within a transaction and will acquire the lock when reading. If you're doing this manually, start a transaction by yourself. For info about transactions read here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/transactions